# Nuxt vue-Router page-transition not working while requestAnimationFrame loop is running

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, vue-router, nuxt.js

I have a problem with the combination of the nuxt/vue-router page-transitions and the js method `rerequestAnimationFrame`. 
I'm animating the container of some items with `rerequestAnimationFrame` and the `transform: translate` CSS property. Like this:

```
const step = timestamp => {
    itemContainer.style.transform =
      'translateX(' + this.animationStep * -1 + '%)'
    this.animationStep = this.animationStep + 1           
    if (this.interrupt) window.requestAnimationFrame(step)
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(step)
```

`this.interrupt` is set to `true` by default. 
The items auf this container including `nuxt-link`(s) for routing to a subpage.

**The Problem:**
While this animation is running and I click a `nuxt-link` the router gets triggered, but the page-transition not. So the subpage page will be displayed directly without any smooth transition between the pages.

If I remove the `requestAnimationFrame` loop the page-transition is triggered correctly and all events `beforeLeave` etc.too.

I tried to to add an onclick event on the items or the container to set the `this.interrupt` property to `false` but this doesn't work. The event is fired, but every router action is running before the next animation frame I think.

So, is there any solution to wait for animation frame and than run the router and transition actions? Or a other way to trigger the transition correctly in this case?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [with the router guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)? With the `beforeRouteLeave` guard you can delay the route change and call `next()` callback whenever the animation has finished.

For example, in your page component you could have this:

```js
{
  async beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    try {
      // Start your amazing async animation here
      await this.$myAmazingAnimationStart()

      // Let's suppose that here the animation start is finished,
      // so now we can call 'next()' to change route
      next()
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('Anim error...')
      next()
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but it was an other error... I copied some elements via the DOM so the reactive functions can not work. I rethink in the `data` way an copied the things the vue way. so the router and transitions works well.